# How come my bot's message.js keeps sending me the same error, and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, typeerror

So I'm currently working on a Discord bot using Discord.js and for some reason, I keep getting the exact same error I've never gotten the error before and I'm relatively new to Discord.js. This is the error:

> Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

This is the code I'm working with:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = (client, message, Discord) => {
    const prefix = (process.env.PREFIX);
    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; // The line I get the error on.
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) ||
                    client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    try{
        command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
    } catch(err){
    
        const ErrorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e6b981')
        .setTitle(`There was an error trying to execute this command!`);
    
        message.reply(ErrorEmbed);
        console.log(err);   
    }
}
```

Code put it on request of MrMythical

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, message, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const eventName = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(eventName, event(client, message, Discord));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

If you can please help!

Comment: I think message.content does not have any function named startsWith. can you please verify that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you execute this function is incorrect. In your file (probably index.js) where you execute message.js, you are most likely passing in the arguments incorrectly.

Make sure you pass them in like this:

`(client, message, Discord)`

client is the instance of `Client` in your index.js, message is the instance of `Message` in your message listener most likely, and Discord is the module discord.js.

How did I figure this out? Every message has a `content` property which is a string. Every string has a `startsWith` function but `message.content` is undefined. This means `message` is not an instance of `Message`

Comment: I'm using something called "event_handler.js" to send client, and Discord I just added message to it but now I get "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

Comment: Can you edit that file into your question please?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Can’t you just do `event(client, message, args)`?

Comment: Can we handle this over Discord?

Comment: No, just change event.bind(…) to event(client, message, Discord) and tell me what happens

Comment: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined"

Comment: Try changing it from arrow function to `function(…) {…}`

Comment: What line do I do that?

Comment: In your module.exports

Comment: I tried that but I'm unable to run the bot as it requires the arrow function(I tried this in the event handler.)

Comment: Make it like this: `module.exports = function(client, message, Discord) {...code here}`

Comment: I get the error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined" and I don't know what function I should put

Comment: I will test it tomorrow and see what’s happening

Comment: Hey um, are you here?

Comment: My bad… I was doing other things. I will try my best to find out the issue

Comment: You find out whats the problem yet?